# Writing to file: number of lines doesn't match

Tags: python, mesh, writetofile

`neighbors_to_file` is supposed to write each triangle face's neighbors into the file `neigh.txt`, separated by a new line. The number of faces in this mesh is 352169, therefore the expected number of lines in `neigh.txt` is 352169 * 3 = 1056507. However, the actual number of lines is only 1055697.

```
import openmesh as om
import os

def neighbors_to_file(mesh):
    file = open("neigh.txt","w")
    for f in mesh.faces(): # iterate over the mesh's faces
        for ff in mesh.ff(f): # iterate over the face's neighbors
            file.write(str(ff.idx()))
            file.write("\n")
    file.close()

path = os.path.join("../meshes", "tr_scan_000.obj")
r_mesh = om.read_trimesh(path)
neighbors_to_file(r_mesh)
```

As far as I know, the mesh is closed, thus no holes in there.

Comment: Does every single triangle have 3 neighbors ? I'm thinking about border effects: maybe triangles on the edge of the mesh do not have 3 neighbors bur maybe only 2 or 1 ? I would explain why to the expected number of lines differs from what you are expecting to have.

Comment: `tr_scan_000.obj` is transformed from its `ply` equivalent where each face has exactly 3 neighbors so I guess that this shouldn't change.

Comment: I would recommend you to check `len(mesh.faces())` to ensure you have the right object number, and check `len(mesh.ff(f)) == 3` each iteration, because your logic looks correct

Comment: Thanks, apparently converting the mesh to another format changed the whole mesh connectivity.